# Conditional switching between vector

Tags: matlab

I have two same dimensioned vectors sig1 and sig2, both have more than 1 million data. With the condition that whenever the value of a vector falls below a threshold, a pointer will point to alternate vector (switching). This way I want to form a new vector sws from the pointer's values. Below code works fine, the only issue is, it takes long time. Is there any other way to speed up the code? :

```
thresh = -70;
i=1;
flag1 = 1; % 1 means sig1, 0 means sig2
flag2 = 0; % 1 means switch happened in this loop, 0 means no switch happened in this loop

while(i <= numel(sws))
    if(flag1 == 1)
        sws(i)=sig1(i);
    else
        sws(i)=sig2(i);
    end
    if(sws(i) < thresh)
        if(flag2==1)
            i=i+1;
        else
            flag1 = ~flag1;
        end
        flag2= ~flag2;
    else
        flag2 = 0;
        i=i+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: did you try `vectorization` ?

Comment: What is the goal of `flag2`? It seems you are trying to prevent switching `flag1` when both vectors are below threshold, but the way you implemented it is a bit vague. What is the desired behavior in this case?

Comment: So you're iterating through one vector, then when that value falls below a threshold, you want to switch iterating through another vector **at the same location**?  The wording is a bit unclear.  I also don't understand what `flag2` is for.  Please attach a small numerical example that illustrates your point.

Comment: the aim of flag2 is to prevent instant switching to avoid ping pong. The goal is to take at least one sample from the array after any switch is made, even though that sample is below the threshold. For example, for a certain i, if both sig1 and sig2 contains sample below threshold, it will switch infinitely if you don't use flag2.

Comment: Without flag 2, you still wouldn't have ping-pong if the index i keeps getting incremented. E.g., why not this way: `while(i <= numel(sws))
    if(flag1 == 1)
        sws(i)=sig1(i);
    else
        sws(i)=sig2(i);
    end
    if(sws(i) < thresh)
            flag1 = ~flag1;
    end
    i=i+1;
end`

Comment: The code in my previous comment takes a value, puts it into sws, then decides whether to switch to another channel, then increments i regardless (so if the switch happened, the next value will be taken from that new channel, whatever it is). Also, the while loop should really be for.